Verb ellipsis in compound sentences
I am writing an essay and want to check if it is correct to omit verbs in the following sentences:

This leads to negative expressions being more nuanced and positive
ones more generic.
This idea did not work, because the quality of the
copies was very poor and the contrast with the original products too
great.

Can I leave it like this, or should it be '...and positive ones being more generic', 'and the contrast with the original products was too great'?
Also, please let me know if there should be a comma before 'and' in these examples!

Personally, I would not use a comma before because. No, don't repeat being. That's awful. [...] and the contrast too great with the original products. Please note (not my rule by the way), we're not supposed to edit things here. But: positive ones, more generic. [it's about the rhythm and breathing]

I like the parallelism with "and the contrast with the original products too great"; I would leave too great where it is, but would agree with Lambie about no comma before because.  The comma before and is discretionary.

Thank you for your suggestions - that's really helpful!

Please keep questions to one topic at a time. It's tempting to add an "extra," unrelated question about commas as long as we're talking about these sentences, but it would be best as its own question so that answers can focus on one thing at a time.

@AndyBonner  + 1 As OP has asked, I have to inform. These rules are from Indiana University, Richmond, USA website. So I am surprised.
Though we don't follow Rule 2, I have seen it at many places.
Rule 1:  (and, but, yet, so, or nor, for) when it joins two complete ideas (independent clauses).
He walked down the street, and then he turned the corner.
Rule 2:  Use a comma to separate each item in a series;
We bought apples, peaches, and bananas today. (series of words)
https://east.iu.edu/student-success/coursework/commas.html

OP had enquired about the deletion of the verb "was" in the sentence:

Can I leave it like this, or should it be '...and positive ones being more generic', 'and the contrast with the original products was too great'?

"Gapping" is a linguistic technique that omits repeated verbs in coordinated clauses to avoid repetition.
In the sentence "This idea did not work, because the quality of the copies was very poor and the contrast with the original products too great".
the verb 'was' ("being" in first sentence) is implied for the subsequent clause.

Reference Collins dictionary:.
gapping.
in British English.
noun (in transformational grammar) a rule that deletes repetitions of a verb, as in the sentence.
Bill voted for Smith, Sam for McKay, and Dave for Harris.
Mary brought the bread, John the cheese, and Bill the wine.


Also, please let me know if there should be a comma before 'and' in these examples!

Yes a comma is required before "and". It is a rule of grammar that you should put a comma before a coordinating conjunction. (For, and, nor, but, or, yet, so)

I think the comma is optional. Especially in the second example, because both clauses are part of the reason introduced by "because", which already has a comma before it.

Upvoted, but a few suggestions: 1) "OP asked about the sentence" ... and then a quote that doesn't contain the entire sentence in question. As long as we're recording material from the answer (not a bad strategy, in case future edits change it), maybe it should include the example sentence. 2) I feel like we're missing a clear and resounding "Yes, this is okay." Also there are a few style issues to check in your paragraph following the block quote—single quotes, failure to close them, period instead of comma, etc. 3) The question about comma usage ideally ought to have been ignored, and...

... the OP encouraged to ask it separately since it has nothing to do with the gapping (though maybe it would be excessive to vote-to-close the current question for it). But the rule is "comma before a coordinating conjunction that joins two independent clauses." The OP's first sentence doesn't qualify, it just has a compound object. I have mixed feelings even about the second one; I'd prefer not to use the comma on it either, but it does end with an independent clause. I'm not sure, though, whether it makes a difference that all this is lodged within a much bigger clause...

Whether the comma is required is a question of style, not grammar. It depends which style guide you choose to follow.

@Barmar The comma before "because" (adverbial clause) is optional. In some grammar books ask us to use a comma before a coordinating conjunction (exception a short clause). I think different rules are followed regarding usage of commas.

Okay, the next day I feel like removing my upvote because this otherwise helpful answer ends with irrelevant and potentially confusing advice about commas (we don't want to give learners the impression that they must put a comma in "peanut butter, and jelly sandwich," and while it's debatable for the OP's second sentence, it's absolutely in the wrong about the first sentence.

@AndyBonner Please check Indiana University Richmond USA link. We bought apples, peaches, and bananas today. (series of words)
https://east.iu.edu/student-success/coursework/commas.html

Oh dear, this is getting more confused. Nobody mentioned series, and the OP's sentences do not qualify (only two items, not three). And IU's unqualified backing of the Oxford comma (though I'm in their camp) should make it clear that these are matters of style, not universal rules that all agree on.
